# Blurry lines possibly resulting from sub-pixel positioning or transforms in Webkit

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, webkit, css-transforms

Webkit is producing blurry lines under certain conditions when transforms are applied to elements. My best guess is that it has to do with the transforms resulting in sub-pixel positioning. If I remove the transforms in these cases, the rendering is corrected. If I change the transform to transform3d, things improve slightly but its still blurry.

Here are my results:

Perfect! (no transform applied)
[image]
Blurry, and gray line shows under triangle (translate(0, -50%) applied)
[image]
Blurry, but no gray line under triangle (translate3d(0, 0, -50%) applied)
[image]

Note that the transforms are being applied on the `Y` parameter, and it's the top border that appears blurry. This supports my sense that it is a sub-pixel positioning/rendering issue.

I have tried coming up with the minimal code necessary for reproducing the issue, but I haven't been successful. Very strange. There must be something else contributing to it on my site, but I can't tell what it is.

Has anyone else seen this issue and therefore have thoughts on the precise cause and solution? It's happening on both Chrome and Safari, but not Firefox.

Comment: Can you provide the minimal code to replicate this behavior?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ is a good resource for hosting said minimal code.

Comment: I have tried coming up with the minimal code necessary for reproducing the issue, but I haven't been successful. Very strange. There must be something else contributing to it on my site, but I can't tell what it is.

Comment: Have a look for positioning that is based on percentages. It can cause weird rounding of numbers which might result in what you're describing

Comment: @darronz yes, I imagine that is a contributing factor as well. Strange that I can't reproduce it outside my site though.